# How to set up custom options (when ticked/chosen a field that shows up for customer to key in) for product?

Tags: magento

I have two types of dresses as products in my Magento site. The first one is dresses with fixed sizes (S, M, L, XL) and the other type is a custom size where the customer will provide me with their sizes for tailor-made.

So I need to set the "Size" options for the customer to choose. The first one is where the customer can choose from the drop-down menu (which I already have) and the second "custom size" option for tailor-made service. The customer checks the box and the options size (field for filling in) appears.

I found some sample which is:

http://www.littlethingsfavors.com/mofmepesufat.html

and to be more accurate something that works like this (but this one is not a Magento)

http://www.tbdress.com/product/Fancy-Trumpet-Mermaid-Sleeveless-Matte-Satin-Ruched-Sweetheart-Court-Train-Wedding-Dress-10792914.html

I have tried with the custom options in Magento but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

I've also stumbled on this thread with the same issue but it seems there is no solution that works:

*[www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/74999/](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/74999/)*

Answer (score 1):

You can set any number of Custom Options for Products as you wish. Locate it in your Admin, 
`Catalog->Manage Products->Product(any)->Custom Options`.

Also for setting different Size and Color for you Products, better prefer configurable product with custom attribute.

- Create an attribute set(`Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute Sets`)
  with attributes of your choice (Add Color and Size attribute, `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`).
- Create Product by preferring the configurable attribute set and customize the options as you wish.

In Magento, we have a small tricky thing, the custom options will be more accessible once you saved the product and reopen for edit. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks V_J_S, but that doesn't seem to solve my issue. Thanks for your comment anyway :)

Comment: Welcome and ready to help you in anyway. But please note you can achieve like(http://www.tbdress.com/product/Fancy-Trumpet-Mermaid-Sleeveless-Matte-Satin-Ruched-Sweetheart-Court-Train-Wedding-Dress-10792914.html) using these options. Thanks